# How to poll for the back button in a Javascript Windows 8 App?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, navigation

I'm trying to incorporate page navigation in my Windows 8 app. I have two pages right now and I am able to go from the home page to the beginning page. There is a different background for both pages. When I navigate from the home page to the beginning page, the background changes, but when I press the back button, the background is still the beginning page background and not the home page background. I need to be able to poll for the Windows 8 built in back button so I can reload the home.html file that I have. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WinJS.Navigation` namespace has a `canGoForward` and `canGoBack` allow you to detect this state.

You could also update your implementation of the navigation implementation to change that background.

Comment: So in theory I would go(pseudocode):

`if(WinJS.Navigation.canGoBack)
{
    point navigator to pages/home/home.html
}`

Comment: Yep. That's all you need to do.